# Python List of Dictionaries[int : tuple] Sum

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries. Each Dictionary has an integer key and tuple value. I would like to sum all the elements located at a certain position of the tuple.

Example:

```
myList = [{1000:("a",10)},{1001:("b",20)},{1003:("c",30)},{1000:("d",40)}]
```

I know i could do something like :

```
sum = 0
for i in myList:
    for i in myList:
        temp = i.keys()
        sum += i[temp[0]][1]
print sum
```

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this ? Thanks

Comment: General rule of thumb: if you're directly using a for loop there is a more pythonic way of doing things.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: I wouldn't say that, there are plenty of pythonic uses for the `for` loop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm certain they exist, but I feel like upwards of 90% of all multi-line for loops are indicators of code that needs to be refactored. To clarify: by directly using a for loop I mean not using in-line syntax.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a cut-and-paste error, but why the double for-loop?  Since there are four items in your original list, you are ending up with a sum of 400 instead of 100.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a generator expression, looping over all the dictionaries then their values:

```
sum(v[1] for d in myList for v in d.itervalues())
```

For Python 3, substitute `d.itervalues()` with `d.values()`.

Demo:

```
>>> sum(v[1] for d in myList for v in d.itervalues())
100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
sum((v[1][1] for v in itertools.chain(*[d.items() for d in myList])))
```

itertools can "chain" together several lists to there are logically one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a more pythonic way:

```
print sum([i[i.keys()[0]][1] for i in myList])
```